# Can Rasa X Chatbot run Python Scripts or OS Commands?

Tags: python, linux, unix, chatbot, rasa

I installed the Rasa X Chatbot on a Ubuntu system to have an chatbot in a webinterface. Now, I can set all Answers that the Rasa X Bot gives. But how can I train Rasa, so that he executes OS Commands.

I want an example dialog like this:

User: "Hey can you make an directory for me called MyDir?"
Bot: "Directory 'MyDir' was successfully created"

In the background the bot has to execute an unix command like "mkdir MyDir". How / Where can I program this stuff? On the webinterface I can only add some responses in textform, but I can't tell the bot that he has to execute os commands or like call some python scripts that execute these os commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your chatbot to execute custom code, you would need to create some [custom actions](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/custom-actions). To run those you need to have a [Rasa Action Server](https://rasa.com/docs/action-server) set up. Also your chatbot needs to know when to call those custom actions. To achieve that you need to add some [training data](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/stories) that show when the chatbot should perform those actions.

I also recommend watching the [Rasa Masterclass](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL75e0qA87dlHQny7z43NduZHPo6qd-cRc). It also covers how to set up custom actions and how to run those in Rasa X.